# string and unequal feature vectors in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

i have string and unequal feature vectors . How do I use it in sklearn? Without conversion to binary

```
x=[["a","b"],["a","d","c"],["b","f"],["c","f","d"]]
y=[1,0,1,0]
from sklearn import ensemble
clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
clf.fit(x,y)
xt=[["b","f","d"],["a","c"]]
clflist=clf.predict(xt)
print(clflist)
```

Comment: If the feature vectors have unequal lengths then how do they line up? Is the nth element of one vector the nth feature, and the same as the nth element of another vector?

Comment: without conversion to binary, it is impossible

Comment: @Denziloe Not necessarily in order. a, b, c, d, f, ... are different features in each vector exists or not.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing what the feature mean vectors mean. Are `a, b, c` and `a, b` three features, with a missing value in the second case or are these two distinct values of one feature? Are the features categorial or ordinal? (i.e. does `'a' > 'b'` make sense?) And what do you mean by conversion to binary?

Comment: @farideh In that case you are inherently talking about binary feature vectors and so converting it to a binary feature vector is the only sensible way to do it.

Comment: @kazemakase for example, if my feature set is '{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"}' . and my sample set is '{s1,s2,s3,s4}' . my feature vectors are: 's1=["a","b"]' ,'s2=["a","d","c"]' ,'s3=["b","f"]', 's4=["c","f","d"]'. and binary: s1=[1,1,0,0,0,0] , s2=[1,0,1,1,0,0,0],....

Comment: @farideh, that much was clear from the structure of `x`. The question is how do *you* interpret these vectors? You need to get them in a matrix representation, but how to do that depends on the semantical interpretation of the data.

Comment: @kazemakase My question is only how can I use string and unequal feature vectors, and this question has no relevance to the interpretation of semantic data.

Comment: @Denziloe my real data is very larg. converting it to binary is very time consuming so I want to use string data.

Comment: Well... you can't. And converting it to strings will be no faster than converting it to binary. Actually it will probably be slower.

Comment: @farideh I see. Unfortunately, the answer is you can't.

Comment: what do you mean by "my real data is very large" ? `sklearn` provides several vectorizers that transform this kind of feature vectors to binary vectors and they are efficient.

Comment: [MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) can solve your issue.